# What is the time complexity(theta) of evaluating an expression using parser module in Python3?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x

I want to know the algorithm or the time complexity that the parser module in Python3 uses in order to `eval` the expressions.

This is my code:

```
import random
import parser

equation_ = '(x**3 + 5*(x**2) - 3*x + 3) + (4*(x**5) - 2*(x**2) + 1)'

code = parser.expr(equation_).compile()
test_cases = [random.randrange(-100, 100) for _ in range(10)]

for x in test_cases:
    print(eval(code))
```

Now, I wanted to know which algorithm has been used or what is the time complexity of the method: `parser.expr()` and `eval()`.

I tried reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/parser.html#parser.expr) but could not figure out, and so was the case with the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Parser/parser.c): parser.c and parser.h

Comment: Are you asking about the complexity of parsing or evaluating? And what is the complexity in terms of, the number of characters in the expression, the number of variables, etc.?

Comment: @Barmar
Both, I have edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: Parsing is O(n), evaluating is the complexity of the equation itself.

Comment: @Barmar and how did you arrive at this?
Looking at the source code or do you know the algorithm already?

Comment: I know this based on what I learned about parsing 40 years ago. In general, parsers don't need to do any nested looping, they just scan the input sequentially.

Comment: All it's doing is pushing tokens and popping tokens into a stack, and creating a nested structure that corresponds to the expression tree.

Comment: Can you answer it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak to the specific algorithm in Python's `parser` library, but in general parsing is O(n). It uses regular expressions to extract a stream of tokens from the text, and then matches this against grammar patterns, which can be done with table lookups. There may be recursion involved to handle nested structures in the grammar, but it's all done with a fixed number of scans over the input. I think Python is a context-free grammar, so it should be parsable with a single pass.

And once the expression is parsed, evaluating it has the same complexity as if you'd written that expression in normal source code -- `eval()` is simply a call into that part of the Python interpreter. If there are no loops in the code, it will be O(n).

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar and sorry for not describing the question at first. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Note that for a complex operation like parsing, "time complexity" is not really very meaningful. The coefficients are going to be much more significant than the growth based on input.

Comment: Noted. Thanks again.